# retriving error from mysql

Tags: php, mysql

i am running while loop which works fine and shows all results as per my requirement but in that after while loop where i am showing datas i want header value from some other database but its not working . where i am doing mistake . i want this ''.$x45.'' value from some other table of same database . this is working fine in other cases but in while loop its not working

```
$res = sql_query("SELECT * from fads  topic order by created desc limit 5");
{
while($row = sql_fetch_array($res)) {
$ead= $row['topic'];
$out .= '<table width="100%"><tr><td style="text-align:left;"><a     href="forums/ead/">'.$ead.'</a></td></tr>
</table>';}


$res1 = sql_query("select * from cry where id='{$nt['id']}'");
$row1 = sql_fetch_array($res1);
$x45=$row1['x45'];

ass(array('title'=>t(''.$x45.''), 'content' => '<div class="toolbar">'.'<div    style="border:0px solid #B2BCA7;margin-bottom:20px;"><div style="padding: 7px; position:   relative;">'.$out.'</div>'));
}
```

Comment: Oh my. Don't nest queries like that. It's an incredible waste of resources. You can gather that information with a `JOIN` statement.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that named array indices can't be specified within quotes. Try echoing the query you're building for `$res1` and I'll bet that the value for `$nt['id']` isn't being inserted correctly. Switch to using concatenation and it should work.

```
$res1 = sql_query("select * from cry where id='{" . $nt['id'] . "}'");
```

Comment: Have you tried echoing `"select * from cry where id='{" . $nt['id'] . "}'"` to see if it actually does contain the query you want?

Comment: echo sql_query("select * from  like this you are telling

Comment: No, the literal command you want is `echo("select * from cry where id='{" . $nt['id'] . "}'");` . The purpose is to find out whether the query you're running contains the actual text you think it does.

Comment: Well, there's your problem. It looks like $nt is supposed to have some ID value in it, but it's either not getting assigned or being set to null. Find where $nt['id'] is set in your code (it's not anywhere in the sample you posted) and figure out how to get it to contain the ID value you want it to have.